# Can I travel to Rome, Italy with only Permesso di Soggiorno and Carta D’identità?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, passports, italy, philippines

I have a Philippine passport and a Permesso di Soggiorno for Italy. This April, I plan to apply for a Carta D’Identità. My Philippine passport will expire on 17th July, 2021.
I was thinking that if I am allowed to travel to Rome with an expired Philippine passport (purpose: to renew the passport), but with a valid Permesso di Soggiorno and a Carta D’Identità. I’m planning to travel to Rome like a month after the passport expires.

Comment: I assume your Permesso di soggiorno is from Italy? Are you currently residing in Italy?

Comment: @zhantongz yes and yes :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a valid Permesso di soggiorno, your stay in Italy remains tolerated despite an expired (or lost) passport, but you should obtain a new valid passport as soon as possible.

You have no restriction on where you can travel within Italy because of the expired passport. However, other restrictions may apply, for example, Covid-related restrictions may prevent or obstruct you from interregional travel, although replacing passport might qualify as a good reason for travel (on this I have no practical knowledge if it would actually qualify as an exception).

Comment: noted. i’m trying to book an appointment to renew my passport but the dates are fully booked so i’m waiting for them to free new slots

Answer (score 0):

The Italian National Identity Card is a fully fledged identity document, released both to nationals and [aliens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(law)) (not these ).

It replaces the passport completely in order to identify an individual, e.g. when boarding a national flight, because it carries both photo and encrypted fingerprints of the holder. You are probably within the Italian territory already today, so it's *not* worth mentioning that the National ID for aliens is not a valid Schengen travel document (but the Residence permit is).

Traveling within the country to visit the Embassy is permitted with a valid National ID. If you skip air travel, it is extremely unlikely that someone will ever ask to see your ID/passport on your journey to Rome.

Comment: For third-country nationals the passport is the travel document. The residence permit serves a proof that you are legally within the Schengen Area (replacement for any otherwise possibly needed visa and entry stamp). **Both** are required outside of Italy.